# I am not able to connect to my SQL Server database, it is showing network or instance related error

Tags: sql-server

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ2J0.png)

I have searched for this problem and someone says enable your SQL Server services but it is showing empty.

Comment: If you **don't see** any services - then you **do NOT** have SQL Server installed. You cannot connect to a non-existing SQL Server ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: Corrupted installation maybe ? Or you didn't uninstall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the sql server. And  press windows + R= run then
type services.msc on that,then select your data base and restart.